# Outlook Auto Response

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a rule set up in outlook that auto responds to emails with a specific ID number in the subject. Is there a way to get this ID from the original email and then use it to personalize the response email?

i.e

```
(Original Email)
Subject: Completed ID 110101
Message: This is the completed ID 110101

(Auto response email)
Subject: Submission
Message: Thank you, the submission of ID 110101 has been Received.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you know VBA you can do it. Google *VBA Outlook read subject line*
Here is one answer to get you started ...
https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/536942-outlook-macro-read-subject-line.html